# How do I set the bone length after setting a new bone matrix?

Tags: python, scripting, bones, transforms

In version 2.77a; the [docs](https://www.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_2_77a_release/bpy.types.EditBone.html#bpy.types.EditBone) show that the `edit_bone.matrix` is no longer *read only*, but a note warns *"does not include bone length"*. Luckily, `edit_bones` also have a property `length` you can set:

> **length**
>
> The distance from head to tail, when set the head is moved to fit the length.

With that in mind, I tried assigning the matrix, then setting the bone's length:

```
bone.matrix = bone_imatrix[0:16]
bone.length = 0.1
```

But when I check the transform of the bone, the `bone.length = 0.1` doesn't reflect what the docs said: *"head is moved to fit length"*. (Hopefully they'll allow moving the tail to fit instead of the head.)

[image]

Head and tail are still the same, making it invalid, and disappears as soon as I change the mode back to *OBJECT*.

I tried using `bone.transform(bone_imatrix, True, True)` but it does nothing (Odd):

```
print( bone_imatrix )
>> <Matrix 4x4 ( 0.0000, -0.0000, -1.0000, -0.0000)
               (-0.0000,  1.0000, -0.0000,  0.0000)
               ( 1.0000, -0.0000,  0.0000, -0.0000)
               (-0.0000,  1.9815, -0.5483,  1.0000)>
```

Here are the values I was expecting:

[image]

**Question**: Why is the matrix getting set but not the length? Is there a better way of assigning the bone matrix?

Answer (score 0):

I am looking for a similar answer, but I may be able to help.

The "forward" (or "backward" if you see moving from head to tail as moving backward) vector direction is +Z (0,0,1), try setting head to (0,0,0), tail to (0,0,1) and then set length and matrix in that specific order.

The problem I am having is that the custom matrix I set, does not remain the same:

IOW: bone.matrix = custom.matrix, bone.matrix ~= custom.matrix BUT bone.matrix != custom.matrix

my current guess is that my custom matrix coming from a left hand coordinate system is something Blender "fixes" behind the scenes to an equivalent matrix, this however makes it hard to import a model and export to the exact same file that was imported on the first place.